# Domino + iPhone push email

Tags: iphone, lotus-domino

I understand there are multiple ways to receive Domino based email on a iPhone, I have already come across Traveller, but since it's resource intensive and the server is running xpages applications, I was hoping for other options. What other options are available to me? Would appreciate suggestions as well as information on how the suggestion can be implemented. Is IMAP an option here at all?

Many thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of quick options are:

- Install Traveller on another server, accessing mail-files on your primary mailserver - thereby reducing load on your web server.
- POP3 - This has been supported in Domino since the year dot, does the job for simple email polling.
- IMAP - Like POP3 only with support for Folders, etc. You need to "IMAP enable" your mail-files first (this just sets up a few views, references, etc).

The final two options won't give you Calendar access though. Also, the final two options would require you to set up some kind of authenticated SMTP to send mails out through your Domino server. No biggy though, it's just all a lot simpler with Traveller.

Comment: Thanks Greg, so if using Traveller, what are the resource implications on the server if another server is not an option at the moment? I think calendar access would be great and preferred, so might end up with Traveller option.

Comment: I personally run it on a pretty low spec machine. Traveler runs as a servlet, so it will invoke the JVM/etc - but if you're already hosting XPages then this should already be loaded. You may not notice a huge performance hit :)
You can always install it; try it; then disable the task if it becomes too much of a load.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [IBM Lotus Notes 8.5.2 and 8.5.3 Traveler performance](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes852-trav-perf/). It states

> To support more than 2000 (or number reached in our tests) active Lotus Notes Traveler users, customers need to deploy more than one Lotus Notes Traveler 8.5.2 64-bit server.
>
> The processor utilization on the Lotus Domino mail server should be monitored to ensure that the mail server can handle the added activity from the Lotus Notes Traveler users at peak load.
>
> Note that Lotus Notes Traveler is a memory-intensive application and it is best to deploy Lotus Domino 64-bit servers on Windows 64-bit operating systems to support large numbers of mobile device users.

As long, as you don't define "resource intensive" and state more info regarding number of concurrent users, machine specs, ... we can't give you better answers.

Comment: Thank you - No. of users is less than 20 and the server is 32 bit (OS and Domino) with 4GB of RAM. So I guess I shouldn't really be worried!!